# How to get number webcams, with using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I get number webcams with using this code:

```
CountCamers := 0;
j := 0;
capture := cvCreateCameraCapture(700);
while Assigned(capture) do
begin
  inc(CountCamers);
  cvReleaseCapture(@capture);
  capture := nil;

  inc(j);
  capture := cvCreateCameraCapture(700 + j);
end;
```

But, sometimes this code give at result number webcams equal 100 (max number camera of domain), but in reality only one webcam is connected. How to get number webcams? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't with OpenCV. Look for another lib that can do that for you in your specific OS. Don't try to find a solution in OpenCV because it simply does not exist

Answer (score 0):

When there is only 1 camera, the index is unused (you can pass -1).
Try instead to check the identity of the opaque struct pointer returned. I think (sorry, not tested because I have just 1 camera attached) that should be unique for each device.

Answer (score 0):

You can to get number of webcams checking if you can to get a Frame. Example in python:

```
def get_num_cameras():
    n = 0 
    num_cameras = 0 
    while n < 100:
        camera = CaptureFromCAM(n)
        if QueryFrame(camera):
            num_cameras += 1
        n += 1
        return num_cameras
```